# Having problems using myString.split("\n");

Tags: java, string, io, split, newline

I need to split an input string into many parts. The splits should occur at "\n" (literally backslash-n, not the newline character).
E.g., I want to turn this:

```
x = [2,0,5,5]\ny = [0,2,4,4]\ndraw y #0000ff\ny = y & x\ndraw y #ff0000
```

into this:

```
x = [2,0,5,5]
y = [0,2,4,4]
draw y #0000ff
y = y & x
draw y #ff0000
```

I would have thought that `stringArray = string.split("\n");` would have been sufficient.

But it gives me the same output as input in the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter Input\n");
    String s = br.readLine();
    NewInterpreter interpreter = new NewInterpreter(s);
    interpreter.run();
}

public NewInterpreter(String input) {
    this.input = input;
    this.index = 0;
    this.inputComponents = input.split("\n");
    System.out.println("Output: ");
    for(String s : inputComponents)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

```
Enter Input
x = [2,0,5,5]\ny = [0,2,4,4]\ndraw x #00ff00\ndraw y #0000ff\ny = y & x\ndraw y #ff0000"
Output: 
x = [2,0,5,5]\ny = [0,2,4,4]\ndraw x #00ff00\ndraw y #0000ff\ny = y & x\ndraw y #ff0000
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: if you define the data member in this way`private String[] inputComponents;` Then the splitting using `\n` should work @Dylan: check the link here https://ideone.com/5pN6xX. as your input has two `\n` thats why the extra new line is coming.

Comment: @VinayakPingale Your sample is wrong. OP gets his input from the user, not a Java string literal. In this case, that makes all the difference in the world. To have equivalent input, you would have to replace all `\n` in your sample string with `\\n`.

Comment: Check it now @RobbyCornelissen : https://ideone.com/5pN6xX

Comment: @VinayakPingale  I have checked it. Doesn't work as per OP's requirements.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're entering `\n` literally (i.e. as opposed to as a newline character), you need to split as follows:

```
string.split("\\\\n");
```

The reason for the complexity is that `split()` takes a regular expression as an argument. When trying to match a literal backslash using a regular expression, it needs to be doubly escaped (once for the regular expression, and once for the string literal).

Comment: Hey I'm getting the same output using "\\n" as the split :/

Comment: Are you sure that the above code by OP doesn't run ? Because i tried the same code by OP and its working; though it works with `\\n` also

Comment: Should I just ignore my println() testing and carry on as if it's working fine?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Forgot that `split` takes a regular expression pattern argument instead of a string literal. Need to double escape the backslash. Tested width OP's sample input and code and works correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

There can't be any linefeeds in text you read via `readLine()`.

*Ergo* you must be looking for literal `\` followed by a literal `n.` (Why?)

*Ergo* you must provide *two* backslashes for the regular expression compiler, and you will have to escape them both once each for the Java compiler. Total: four.

*Alternatively* you are just attempting the impossible, trying to split on linefeeds that aren't there. Maybe the input is already split adequately by just calling `readLine()?`