# Discrepancy in String array length with the same regex for the same input

Tags: java, regex

Below code is split the string on `\n`. For small input it does work but       long input it is not working as expected for same `\n`.
   Inorder to investigate the same discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886583/having-problems-using-mystring-split-n/).
Written testcase to verify the behavior.
   It is working as expected for `\n` where as there was one suggestion in the answer to test with `\\\\n` as regex when I tried with that program I got difference in string array length calculation.
   Below having code and the discrepancy I found.

```
public String[] token=new String[10];
public Addnumber(String input) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.token=input.split("\n");
    System.out.println("Inside constructor Length="+token.length);
    for(String s:token)
        System.out.println(s);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     String input="hi\niam\nhere";
     String input1="hi\niam\nhere";
     String input2="x = [2,0,5,5]\ny = [0,2,4,4]\n\ndraw y #0000ff\ny = y & x\ndraw y #ff0000";
     new Addnumber(input1);//calculating via constructor
     new Addnumber(input2);
     String[] istring=new String[10];
     //Calculating in main method
     // General expression of \n
     istring=input.split("\n");
     System.out.println("Length calcluated when \n as regex="+istring.length);
     for(String s:istring)
          System.out.println(s);    
     istring=input2.split("\\\\n");   //Check the  regex used here
     System.out.println("Length calcluated when \\\\n as regex="+istring.length);
     for(String s:istring)
         System.out.println(s);
}
```

On Executing this  program output as follows

```
Inside constructor Length=3
hi
iam
here
Inside constructor Length=6
x = [2,0,5,5]
y = [0,2,4,4]

draw y #0000ff
y = y & x
draw y #ff0000
Length calcluated when 
as regex=3
hi
iam
here
Length calcluated when \\n as regex=1
x = [2,0,5,5]
y = [0,2,4,4]

draw y #0000ff
y = y & x
draw y #ff0000
```

Please note when `\n` is regex then the length of string array is  expected but when `\\\\n` as regex it is showing the length as 1 but
    the contents split are same as previous. Why  discrepancy in the length calculation when regex expression changes??
:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you somewhat missed the point of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29886604/3558960) to the aforementioned question.

When splitting a string using `split("\\n")`, you split it by the newline character.

When splitting a string using `split("\\\\n")`, you split by the literal sequence `\n`.

In the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29886583/3558960), the string is obtained through user input, and the user enters `\n` literally. Therefore, `\\\\n` needs to be used to correctly split it.

If you want to simulate the literal `\n` user input, your sample string would need to look like this:

```
String input2 = "x = [2,0,5,5]\\ny = [0,2,4,4]\\n\\ndraw y #0000ff\\ny = y & x\\ndraw y #ff0000";
```

If you're wondering why in your last sample, it displays a length of 1, but still renders the string parts on separate lines: it's just the newlines in your input string that are being rendered.

Comment: Here the question is why string array length value is showing 1 when it is able to split the content successfully?

Comment: Nothing is split. Your output just renders the newlines that are in your input string.

Comment: Thanks Robby for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`split("\n")` splits by a newline. You have that in your string, so you get a split.

`split("\\\\n")` splits by a backslash and a newline. Both regular expressions and Java Strings have escape semantics, so string `"\\\\n"` is actually regular expression `\\n` (backslash and `n`). `"\n"` produces a literal newline in the regular expression; `"\\n"` produces a regular expression `\n`, which regular expression engine reads as newline. Both of those would give you the split on newlines; but presumably, your string does not contain the backslash followed by an `n`, so the `split("\\\\n")` fails and returns you the one element you started with.